# Invalid command name in Tcl when using format

Tags: format, tcl

I'm running the following commands

```
set full_pin_name [format "%s %s" $top_cell $encoded_name]
puts "full_pin_name is $full_pin_name"
```

and I get the following error:

```
full_pin_name is invalid command name "A" B
```

when `top_cell` equals A and `encoded_name` equals B.
Why is this happening?

Comment: Are you positive `top_cell` contains `A`? It looks like it contains `invalid command name "A"`. Do you somewhere have `catch {something} top_cell`?

Answer (score 3):

I suspect the problem is with your $top_cell variable, which has the value **invalid command name "A"**. To check, try the following line before your format line:

```
puts ">$top_cell<"
```

If indeed, $top_cell value has a problem, you can then trace back to the last **set** command. Let us know if it fixes your problem, or we might try some other approaches.

Comment: +1 i'd say this is almost certainly right, unless Amir confirms his original assertion that top_cell eq A was correct.

Answer (score 3):

Try repeating this in a plain Tcl shell, it works.  Something is different in your Tcl shell.

Try

```
info body set
```

and

```
info body format
```

If either report something other than `set isn't a procedure` or `format isn't a procedure` then you have your culprit.

Comment: @glenn I suspect `set` b/c `format` doesn't have any reference to `full_pin_name`...

Answer (score 1):

May be this code runs in a namespace which has the `set` command defined in it?
To demonstrate:

```
% namespace eval foo {
    proc set args {
      puts hey!
    }
    proc whatever {top_cell encoded_name} {
      set full_pin_name [format "%s %s" $top_cell $encoded_name]
      puts "full_pin_name is $full_pin_name"
    }
  }
% ::foo::whatever A B
hey!
can't read "full_pin_name": no such variable
%
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell without a TCL interpreter here it should work assuming a normal interpreter with format defined. so it looks like maybe format has been renamed or doesn't exist as a command in the interpreter you are using?

To get you going you don't really need format to join strings anyway

set fill_pin_name "$top_cell $encoded_name"

should so what you need

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your code looks like this:

```
set encoded_name B  
if { [catch {[A]} top_cell]} {
    set full_pin_name [format "%s %s" $top_cell $encoded_name]
    puts "full_pin_name is $full_pin_name"
}
```

The result is:

```
full_pin_name is invalid command name "A" B
```